# Async method with Task.Run Freeze UI (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf

i'm trying to do a long time running operation in an async method with Task.Run like follow:

```
private async void button_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Run(() => LongOperation());
}
```

this method is called directly from the UI. However the UI is Freezing until the long operation is completed, but i don't understand why.
Is there a way to avoid this?
Thanks

Comment: you're awaiting the result

Comment: What's `LongOperation` doing?

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example please?

Comment: up to now I cannot reproduce your problem, I use `Thread.Sleep(5000)` or `Task.Delay(5000)` in `LongOperation()` and the GUI does not freeze in either of the cases

Comment: It may hang the UI if you are invoking (inside `LongOperation`) an `Action` using the `Dispatcher`  static class. smth like this: `Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(10000);
            }), DispatcherPriority.Render);`

Comment: Ok the problem is inside LongOperation(), if I insert a Thread.Sleep instead of LongOperation everything works fine.. i will provide an example asap

Comment: you should use `await Task.Run(() => {Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(()=>LongOperation())});` instead of  `Task.Run(() => LongOperation());` , Note: test your project in release mode